# How to Create a folder into My Documents or another Path?

Tags: c#

Am a newbie in C#. I would like to Create a Folder with a Specific name into My Documents when my Windows Form load and if the Folder Name already exist it does not do anything.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventsArgs e)
{

}
```

Can anyone help me with the codes?

Comment: You can use the `Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments` enumeration And `System.IO.File` to achieve.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Special folder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.specialfolder(v=vs.110).aspx) enum:

```
Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments), "MyDirectory"));
```

Comment: Yes , Thank you was just wondering on the Title , and to create a sub folder inside it you use same code ?

Comment: @The_Little_Cousin you can add more folders to `Path.Combine` method

Comment: New Question~ When the software Load it create a Folder into MyDocuments. `Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments), "F.U.T.U.R.E"));` Now I want to create another folder Inside this when I press on a button. Such that Inside the Folder F.U.T.U.T.E in My Document I can create another folder. Is this possible, if yes how?

Comment: @The_Little_Cousin please, ask new question not in comment, do it in new question

Comment: Something to remark, Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments will work also in linux